# Optimize docker image build size with curl

Tags: linux, docker, curl, dockerfile, debian

I need to install on docker the latest version of curl

when using the following the docker size is ~140MB

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl wget ca-certificates
```

This use curl 7.64

when using the following

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends wget build-essential ca-certificates libcurl4 && \
    wget https://curl.se/download/curl-7.73.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf curl-7.73.0.tar.gz && cd curl-7.74.0 && \
    ./configure && make && make install && \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove build-essential && \
```

The docker image size is `240MB`, I've tried to remove the build essintials which reduce the size from `440` to `240` , is there a way to remove this additional `~100MB` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you are close to the solution. The one you missed is to delete the curl source package.

So next should make the image reduce:

```
FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends wget build-essential ca-certificates libcurl4 && \
    wget https://curl.se/download/curl-7.73.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf curl-7.73.0.tar.gz && cd curl-7.73.0 && \
    ./configure && make && make install && \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove build-essential && \
    cd .. && rm -fr curl-7.73.0.tar.gz curl-7.73.0
```

Without Curl:

```
$ docker images abc:1
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
abc                 1                   d742bfdf5fa6        25 seconds ago      148MB
```

With curl & source package delete:

```
$ docker images abc:2
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
abc                 2                   afe3d404852a        27 minutes ago      151MB
```

Additional, if you delete apt cache with `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` in Dockerfile, if will be smaller:

```
$ docker images abc:3
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
abc                 3                   5530b0e9b44f        2 minutes ago       134MB
```

Another solution maybe use [multistage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), you could use `./configure --prefix=xxx` to set a default install location, then `stage1` just used to build `curl`, while `stage2` copy the xxx folder from `stage1` to final image.

Answer (score 1):

You should inclide `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` into your RUN instruction to remove apt index files and might include `apt-get clean` to remove any other remaining package file.

Apart from that, you could also try using the *slim* image version, according to Docker Hub [debian:10.7-slim](https://hub.docker.com/layers/debian/library/debian/10.7-slim/images/sha256-d70fe252be511834ae8f685a90b0a658539c99c4a87f79c41831b09be0fee705?context=explore) is almost half size (~24Mb vs ~48Mb)

Finally, you can execute `du -h | sort -h` on a container from your generated image to find out where is the remaining space usage.

Answer (score 1):

Using multistage-build as suggested by atline :

```
FROM debian:10.7 AS builder

WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir /app/usr2

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends wget build-essential ca-certificates libcurl4 && \
    wget https://curl.se/download/curl-7.73.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf curl-7.73.0.tar.gz && cd curl-7.73.0 && \
    ./configure --prefix=/app/usr2 && make install

FROM debian:10.7

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y wget ca-certificates &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=builder /app/usr2/. /usr
```

Final size is 129MB